# Joining two tables to keep selected values and nulls

Tags: sql, teradata

I have got two tables that I need to join. The second table is used to filter the records from the first table.

- table1.parameter
- table2.parameter; table2.parameter_group

The result should include all records from table1 for a certain parameter_group but also records where the parameter is null.
What I have is:

```
table1 LEFT JOIN table2  
ON table1.parameter=table2.parameter  
WHERE table2.parameter_group IS 'A' OR table1.parameter IS NULL
```

My question is - is this the most effective way of achieving the goal? Point is that each of the filters (parameter_group IS 'A' OR table1.parameter IS NULL) target just few percents of records from the very large table1.
I assume this is about clarifying (explaining to me) the processing order... Thanks for help.

Comment: Your query and Gordon's answer return different answer sets. Your query (after fixing the invalid `IS 'A'` syntax) results in an Inner join, while Gordon's returns all rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all rows in `table1` along with matches from `table2` for `parameter_group = 'A'`, then move the condition to the `ON`:

```
table1 LEFT JOIN
table2  
ON table2.parameter = table1.parameter  AND
   table2.parameter_group = 'A'
```

Your method does not always work.  If `table2` has a parameter that is *not* `'A'`, then it will be filtered out.

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks for reply. This is exactly what I am trying to achieve - records from table1 for a certain parameter_group e.g. 'A' AND nulls.

Answer (score 0):

So you want all rows where table1.parameter IS NULL plus all rows where table1.parameter matches a row in table2 that has table2.parameter_group='A'?

```
table1 LEFT JOIN table2  
ON table1.parameter=table2.parameter /* matching condition */
  AND table2.parameter_group = 'A' /* only try to match these rows */
WHERE table1.parameter IS NULL /* keep rows with NULL from table1 */
  OR table2.parameter IS NOT NULL /* plus keep matched rows */
```